# calling 2 url with web client spring boot with in sequential order

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

This question is web flux spring boot related. I have 2 web clients, one that makes a call to a url to get accounts then I send those accounts to an object mapper to get mapped to a POJO. Then I use second web client to make a call to second url with those accounts. Can anyone tell me how I can make them execute in sequence ?

In current scenario by the time I get response back from first web client and response goes to object mapper, second web client fires up and accounts in request body goes as null.

Any input would be appreciated.

thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Cast the `WebClient` output to `Mono<YouPojo>` and use flatMap to call the next service you want.

```
    WebClient client1 = null;
    WebClient client2 = null;

    Mono<String> finalResult = client1.get()
            .uri("https://example.com/service-1")
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String.class)
            .flatMap(result -> client2.post()
                    .uri("https://example.com/service-2")
                    .body(BodyInserters.fromFormData("result", result))
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToMono(String.class));
```

As you see in the above, we have two clients `client1` and `client2` that we use them to call the corresponding services. You can combine the results of `Mono`s with `map` or `flatMap` operations.

Comment: thanks, so I have another file that takes the accounts retrieved from first call and use it in request body for second call. According to your solution that will happen in BodyInserters? because request body has to match the format for 2nd web client post call. Accounts from first call will be just part of bigger POJO in request body.

Comment: Yeah, probably it can solve your issue. I used the `BodyInserters#fromFormData` to pass the result to `client2`.

Comment: so i think in faltMap with { } I can have something like: Pojo.setAccounts(request.getAccounts) and then send that sepcific pojo in requestbody. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can do whatever you want and then subscribe to the latest `Mono` to run the flow sequentially.

Answer (score -2):

By default webclient is a non-blocking I/O. Considering you are using ObjectMapper to convert the response from the first call. You can use block() method to make it blocking call.

```
Example:
webClient.get().uri("http:/sdfsdf.com/sdsd").retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class).block();
```

Comment: I tried using .block() but got exception (cannot use .block()) so had to remove it

Comment: can you tell me what is the exception you are receiving ?

Comment: It is not recommended to call the block operation in reactive system.

Comment: block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-http-nio-4